# How can i insert values with implode, into database

Tags: php

I'm recording values inside an textbox, and i'm using implode:

```
<input type="text" name="log_user_id" value="
<?php
foreach ($array as $key){
$userarr[] = $key['user_id'];
}
echo implode($userarr, ",");
?>
" />
```

Now i want to insert those values into my table, but it only reads the first value from the implode.

I tried to do that by far:

```
$test = implode(",",$log_user_id);
$insert ="INSERT INTO email_logs(template_id, users_id, application_id) VALUES ('" . $log_temp_id . "', '" . $test . "', '" . $log_app_id . "')";
```

Comment: **warning** that method introduces sql injection attacks!

Comment: Building SQL like that is leaving you open to `SQL Injection`. You should either use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

Comment: Hint : explode the imploded string and use the resultant array.

Comment: Thanks for the advices, i will totally change my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be wrong but I think you only have a vague idea of what `implode()` does. Let's have a look at [the manual](http://php.net/implode):

> `string implode ( string $glue , array $pieces )`
>
> Join array elements with a glue string.
>
> Returns a string containing a string representation of all the array
>   elements in the same order, with the glue string between each element.

So "it only reads the first value from the implode" doesn't make much sense: the whole point of the function is to combine several values into a single string.

I suspect you want to do the opposite operation, [explode()](http://php.net/explode):

```
$insert ="INSERT INTO email_logs(template_id, users_id, application_id)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
foreach( explode(',', $log_user_id) as $test ){
    $values = array($template_id, $test, $application_id);
    $your_db_object->execute($insert, $values);
}
```